# using '#' in group_vars for ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to use a slack channel name inside an ansible (v2.1) playbook.  I tried specifying the slack channel name in the group_vars as follows:

**config**

```
slack_channel: "'#'my-test-tmp"
```

**playbook**

```
- include: notifications.yml  slack_msg="testing slack message"
```

**notifications.yml**

```
- name: Send notification message via Slack
  local_action:
    module: slack
    domain: test.slack.com   ##changed for SO
    token: "{{ slack_token }}"
    msg: "{{ slack_msg }}"
    channel: "{{ slack_channel }}"
    username: "{{ slack_username }}"
```

However, when I use the slack module, the channel name is not read correctly (the error message shows the slack channel name as #'#'my-test-tmp).  Any thoughts on how I can go about fixing this?  When I use the actual slack channel in the notifications playbook, the slack message is sent across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I did not need to add the hash sign in the channel name when using the slack module for ansible (it gets added by default).  As per YAML syntax rules, using single quotes should allow escaping characters like # (please correct if wrong).

**config**

```
slack_channel: "my-test-tmp"
```